# generate ill-conditioned data for testing floating point summation

Tags: java, floating-point

I have implemented a [Kahan floating point summation algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm) in Java. I want to compare it against the built-in floating point addition in Java and infinite precision addition in Mathematica. However the data set I have is not good for testing, because the numbers are close to each other. (Condition number ~= 1)

Running Kahan on my data set gives all most the same result as the built-in `+`.

Could anyone suggest how to generate a large amount of data that can potentially cause serious rounding off error?

Comment: take a look at [this ibm site](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0114/) in the part of "rouding errors". Basically, you need to generate some numbers that cannot be expressed as a binary with negative exponent. For example, 0.5 = 2^-1, but 0.1 is not. This [site](http://www.intel.com/standards/floatingpoint.pdf) from intel also gives a good theory about it. And you want to make your java crash due to rounding problems, [take a look at this site](http://www.exploringbinary.com/java-hangs-when-converting-2-2250738585072012e-308/) about using the number 2.2250738585072012e-308 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However the data set I have is not good for testing, because the numbers are close to each other.

It sounds like you already know what the problem is.  Get to it =)

There are a few things that you will want:

- Numbers of wildly different magnitudes, so that most of the precision of the smaller number is lost with naive summation.
- Numbers with different signs and nearly equal (or equal) magnitudes, such that catastrophic cancellation occurs.
- Numbers that have some low-order bits set, to increase the effects of rounding.

To get you started, you could try some simple three-term sums, which should show the effect clearly:

```
1.0 + 1.0e-20 - 1.0
```

Evaluated with simple summation, this will give `0.0`; clearly incorrect.  You might also look at sums of the form:

```
a0 + a1 + a2 + ... + an - b
```

Where `b` is the sum `a0 + ... + an` evaluated naively.

Answer (score 0):

You want a heap of high precision numbers? Try this:

```
double[] nums = new double[SIZE];
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    nums[i] = Math.rand();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are we talking about number pairs or sequences?

If pairs, start with 1 for both numbers, then in every iteration divide one by 3, multiply the other by 3. It's easy to calculate the theoretical sums of those pairs and you'll get a whole host of rounding errors. (Some from the division and some from the addition. If you don't want division errors, then use 2 instead of 3.)

Answer (score 0):

By experiment, I found following pattern:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(1.0 / 3 - 0.01 / 3);

    System.out.println(1.0 / 7 - 0.01 / 7);

    System.out.println(1.0 / 9 - 0.001 / 9);
}
```

I've subtracted close negative powers of prime numbers (which should not have exact representation in binary form). However, there are cases then such expression evaluates correctly, for example

```
    System.out.println(1.0 / 9 - 0.01 / 9);
```

You can automate this approach by iterating power of subtrahend and stopping when multiplication by appropriate value doesn't yield integer number, for example:

```
    System.out.println((1.0 / 9 - 0.001 / 9) * 9000);
    if (1000 - (1.0 / 9 - 0.001 / 9) * 9000 > 1.0)
        System.out.println("Found it!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Scalacheck might be something for you. Here is a short sample:

```
cat DoubleSpecification.scala
import org.scalacheck._

object DoubleSpecification extends Properties ("Doubles") {
        /* 
            (a/1000 + b/1000) = (a+b) / 1000
            (a/x    + b/x   ) = (a+b) / x
        */
        property ("distributive") = Prop.forAll { (a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) => 
            (c == 0 || a*1.0/c + b*1.0/c == (a+b) * 1.0 / c)            }
}       

object Runner { 
    def main (args: Array[String]) {
        DoubleSpecification.check
        println ("...done")
    }
}
```

To run it, you need scala, and the schalacheck-jar. I used version 2.8 (I don't have to say, that your c-path will vary):

```
 scalac -cp /opt/scala/lib/scalacheck.jar:. DoubleSpecification.scala 
 scala -cp /opt/scala/lib/scalacheck.jar:. DoubleSpecification
! Doubles.distributive: Falsified after 6 passed tests.                       
> ARG_0: 28 (orig arg: 1030341)
> ARG_1: 9 (orig arg: 2147483647)
> ARG_2: 5
```

Scalacheck takes some random values (orig args) and tries to simplify these, if the test fails, in order to find simple examples.